# PHP Dompdf : Incorrect item location

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I use Dompdf to generate a pdf from an html.

Before using the Dompdf library, I built the html to have a preview directly on my browser.

Here is the result when I read html via my browser:

[image: html preview]

The problem is related to Dompdf. The result is not the same as on my browser:

[image: pdf preview]

As you can see, the elements are not placed correctly:

- I need the logo and the term "RELEVE DE COMPTE" on the same line. The
  logo on the left and, "Statement of Account" in the middle.
- The same goes for the company’s information. In the pdf, it’s at the
  bottom.

My Dompdf function:

```
public function render(string $html)
{
    $pdf = new Dompdf();
    $pdf->loadHtml($html);
    $pdf->setPaper('A3');
    $pdf->render();
    $pdf->stream();
}
```

My html/css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title>Statement</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            padding: 50px;
            font-family: -webkit-pictograph, 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .header {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .header-logo {
            width: 30%;
        }

        .header-title {
            width: 30%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .header-baseline {
            color: #3E5064;
        }

        .spacer {
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
            margin: 1em;
        }

        .infos {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            margin-bottom: 8em;
        }

        .infos > div > div > p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .infos > div > div > h3 {
            margin: 0;
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 0.3em;
        }

        .user-info {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .agent-info {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .statement-first-balance {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .statement-first-balance-period {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .statement-first-balance-amount {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .statement-operations {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .statement-operations-debit {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .statement-operations-credit {
            text-align: right;
        }

        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        table > thead > tr {
            height: 3em;
            background-color: #F7F9FF;
        }

        table > thead > tr > th {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        table > tbody > tr {
            height: 3em;
        }

        .statement-recap {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .statement-recap-amount {
            width: 40%;
            margin-left: 60%;
        }

    </style>
    <link
        href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900italic,900'
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-logo">
        <img alt="agent-logo" class="agent-image"
             src=""
             width="70%">
        <span class="agent-name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="header-title">
        <h1>RELEVE DE COMPTE</h1>
        <p class="header-baseline">Compte - en euros</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-page"></div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="infos">
    <div class="user-info">
        <div>
            <h3>firstName lastName</h3>
            <p>test address</p>
            <p>11111 Town</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>IBAN</h3>
            <p>AA1111111111111111111111111</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>BIC</h3>
            <p>AZERTYUIOPQ</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="agent-info">
        <div>
            <h3>Company</h3>
            <p>Company address</p>
            <p>11111 Town</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="statement-first-balance">
    <div class="statement-first-balance-period">
        <p>du 2022-02-04 au 2022-02-27</p>
    </div>
    <div class="statement-first-balance-amount">
        <p>Votre précédent solde</p>
        <h3>216.25 €</h3>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I don’t understand why rendering from the browser is OK but the PDF is not OK. Could you please help me?

Comment: _"I don’t understand why rendering from the browser is OK but the PDF is not OK."_ - they are two very different things ... The library renders the content itself, and has limitations in its CSS support. Which features/properties do have what level of support, you can check here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

Comment: It might also simply be an issue of what width is available to begin with - if your content renders narrower in the PDF than it does in your browser window, that could also explain the difference. In that case, develop in the browser using a window width that matches the width of the PDF.